# Setting variable in if-case in Qt

Tags: qt, if-statement

I have a problem setting a variable in an if-case. Here's my code:

```
void ExcelResultFileWriter::setCombineP835(bool option){
    if(option == true){
        cout << "dario" << endl;
        this->combineSheets = true;
    }
    else{
        cout << "kein dario" << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an address error when he tries to set the variable combineSheets. Does anyone have an idea why? When I'm only printing out the "dario" it works fine, but when it comes to setting the variable I'm getting the error. The variable is of course defined as

```
bool combineSheets
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: it seems there is nothing wrong in this piece of code, it may be memory corruption or something like that

Comment: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000040

Comment: I tried to change the variable name, but it didn't help. Do you have any hint or solution how I could fix that?

Comment: Your example doesn't compile - make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve), and you'll either (1) discover the problem for yourself, or (2) attract high-quality answers that can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid instance of your class:

A)

```
ExcelResultFileWriter * class;
class->setCombineP835(true);
```

will crash since class is not instantiated/created.

B) If you have:

```
ExcelResultFileWriter * class = new ExcelResultFileWriter();
class->setCombineP835(true);
```

It should work.

C) If you have:

```
ExcelResultFileWriter class;
class.setCombineP835(true);
```

my answer is irrelevant.